# Getting certain types in a namespace

Tags: c#, types

```
namespace BaseNameSpace
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual string ClassName()
        {
           return "BaseClass";
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class Class1: BaseClass
    {
        public override string ClassName()
        {
            return "ClassName1";
        }
    }
    public class Class2: BaseClass
    {
        public override string ClassName()
        {
            return "ClassName2";
        }
    }
    //.... similar classes follow .... ->
}
```

Is it possible to only get some of the types in the namespace, based on the ClassName-property? For instance I only want 'ClassName1' but not the rest.

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                  .Where(t => t.NameSpace.Equals("MyNamespace"))
                  .ToArray<Type>();
```

Comment: those look like member functions that could be tricky to figure out how to construct those instances. why do you have a `ClassName` method anyway?

Comment: you should use an attribute for this purpose to decorate your class, since it is a metadata. Also, the classname method is not static and hence is available on an instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use an attribute to decorate your classes and filter the types using it, as shown below.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
    public class NameAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public NameAttribute(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
    }

    [Name("Class1")]
    public class SomeClass
    {

    }
```

Now you can use below code for filtering the types.

```
var filteredTypes = yourAssembly.GetTypes().Where(type => 
                {
                    var nameAttrib = type.GetCustomAttribute<NameAttribute>();
                    return nameAttrib != null && "Class1".Equals(nameAttrib.Name);
                });
```

However, in case the name is not known at compile time, but available at runtime, you should make the `ClassName()` method static. Then you can filter it as below.

```
    var filteredTypes = yourAssembly.GetTypes().Where(type =>
        {
            var method = type.GetMethod("ClassName", BindingFlags.Static);
            return method != null && "Class1".Equals(method.Invoke(null, null));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Type[] types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
              .Where(t => t.Namespace.Equals("MyNamespace") && t.Name=="Class1")
              .ToArray<Type>();
```